# Game is in landscape-only but view is in portrait?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm trying to draw a line from the bottom middle to the center of the screen. The values I was using for my two points seemed really odd so I knew something was off. I changed the aspect mode to aspectFit to see what was happening and lo and behold my view seemed to be in portrait even though my app specifies landscape. Does anyone know what is causing this? In the build settings I have only landscape checked.

[image]

Comment: The answer might have been because my GameScene.sks file dimensions were in portrait mode? I don't know how the .sks file and .swift file relate so I'm confused here.

Comment: Check the scene size.

Comment: That is how aspectFit works. The whole scene will be visible, but letterboxing may occur. Make scene the same size of a view ( scene.size = view.bounds.size)